# How to bubble event in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I have a winforms application with a parent panel contains `PictureBox` and `Label`.

The application has an event on **mouse enter** on the *parent panel* to do some animation that hides the picturebox and shows the label.

It also has another event on **mouse leave** to handle the animation that hides the label and shows picture box.

What's happening is when mouse enters panel, animation kicks in and does what it does, but when the mouse enters label it practically leaves panel and the reverse animation kicks in.

My question is -

- how can I prevent mouse leave event when my mouse enters child control of the panel?

Comment: check in your mouse leave event if the mouse is still within the bounds of the panel

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Hope you don't mind as I have tidied up your question a bit. 
  Normally would have been better if you showed some code for this sort of question.  [mcve].  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @MickyD for doing that.. My question is now more readable and way clearer even for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mouse is still in the panel

```
private void Panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender as Panel).ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
    {
        //do animation
    }
}
```